# Automatically navigate to first routerLink in an *ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a "feed" of various items (different components). Each has a routerLink which changes the view in the router-outlet beside the feed. I want to navigate the view to the first item in the feed when the feed is initialized.

```
<div class="item-container">
  <ng-container
        *ngFor="let feedItem of items"
        [ngSwitch]="feedItem.type"
      >
        <component-1
          [routerLink]="['type1', feedItem.item.id]"
          [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
          ...
          *ngSwitchCase="FeedItemType.Type1"
        ></component-1>
        <component-2
          [routerLink]="['type2', feedItem.item.id]"
          [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
          ...
          *ngSwitchCase="FeedItemType.Type2"
        ></component-2>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Do your navigation under `ngAfterViewInit()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a better approach here. When you are defining your routes, you can specify a default route for the parent component.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'type1', pathMatch: 'full' },   // <--- default child route
            { path: 'type1', component: Type1Component },
            { path: 'type2', component: Type2Component },
        ],
    },
];
```

So when you navigate to `/parent`, it will automatically redirects to `/parent/type1`.

Comment: Great suggestion, however there's no telling which type or what the ID of the first item in the feed will have at any given time until the feed is loaded (route could be something like /feed/type1/12389 or /feed/type2/92823), so I don't think this would work for me. Each feed item has a routerLink on it (`[routerLink]="['type1', feedItem.item.id]"`) so I felt it easiest to just find the first one and navigate to that. Let me know if you have a different solution for that because I don't really like the one I have either.

Comment: Why don't you specify your routes like `/feed/12389/type1` instead? If you do so, this approach can be applied. Also, I think it would be a better design. In your routes, first you select the feed `id` and then select the type of feed which you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@zyz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/xyz), I was able to solve this issue with the following:

```
@ViewChildren(RouterLink) feedItems: QueryList<RouterLink>;

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.feedItems.changes.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(items => {
    if (items.first) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(items.first.urlTree);
    }
  });
}
```